# Loading data for Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, neural-network

I have to work with two text files, where there are several reviews from hotels. Next to each review there is a value, indicating whether it is a truthful review or a deceptive review.
In order to deal with the test and training set, I have this part of the code:

```
import csv
x_train = list()
y_train = list()
with open('TRAINING_ALL.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        x_train.append(row[0])
        y_train.append(int(row[1]))



x_test = list()
y_test = list()
with open('TEST_ALL.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    x_test.append(row[0])
    y_test.append(int(row[1]))
```

Then I have to use a neural network for classification. However, in the loading data part I get stuck:

```
print('Loading data...')
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)
```

And I get:

```
Loading data...
480 train sequences
320 test sequences
Pad sequences (samples x time)
```

So far good. It reads the correct numbers of sequences. then the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "ould take a quick dip in the pool. I toured the hotel as my niece is planning her wedding and just so happens to live close to the hotel. The ' Chagall Ballroom ', was elegant enough for such an occa
```

What is the correct input to give to this piece of code?

Notice that the code originally works fine as follows (taking a dataset from imdb):

```
print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)
```

Probably x_train and x_test are not with the proper format?

Comment: Can you give the first few lines of an example input file? Do comments or other columns have new line characters?

Comment: The original input file is like this (before the x_train, y_train separation): https://ibb.co/cfrVhR

Then the x_train is a list containing all the reviews i.e. the first column. https://ibb.co/g9dt2R

Comment: Can you also give the full stack trace? Which line of your code causes the error?

Comment: You should use a debugger or `print()` statements to view the values of `row[0]` and `row[1]` in your for loop. They are not what you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the data from the csv file you are loading also the first line containing the columns name, you can easly check that looking at the first element in x_train and x_test. If that's the case you can skip the first line like this

```
import csv
x_train = list()
y_train = list()
with open('TRAINING_ALL.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        x_train.append(row[0])
        y_train.append(int(row[1]))



x_test = list()
y_test = list()
with open('TEST_ALL.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        x_test.append(row[0])
        y_test.append(int(row[1]))
```

Comment: Still not working. There are no column names in the file, it's just made of a column with reviews and another column with 0s or 1s

Comment: the error message is telling you that you are trying to convert 'ould take a quick dip in the pool. I toured the hotel as my niece is planning her wedding and just so happens to live close to the hotel. The ' Chagall Ballroom ', was elegant enough for such an occ' into a number, try to search this string inside the CSV file, or make sure you are pointing to the right file if it's not suppose to contains any string